# Prove $\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n}=0$ and $\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n}= \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $b_{n}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}n, & \text { if } n \text { even } \\ \frac{1}{n}, & \text { if } n \text { odd }\end{array}\right.$

The exercise actually just ask me to find it and not proof it. This is my results:

$$
\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n} = 0 \quad\text{and } \quad \limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n} = \infty
$$

But I will like to learn how to proof this kind of things. Using some kind of $\epsilon$-proof will be very satisfying. But I have never tried proving something which includes limes inferior and limes superior. I will appreciate some help :-)

Kind regard,

EDIT I have not moved forward yet. I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use subsequences. It is easy to find a subsequence converging to zero and another one to $\infty$. Based on those subsequences, you can as you wish make $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proves.

**Example for $\liminf$**

By definition: $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\inf\limits_{m \ge n } b_m\right)$. Take $1 >\epsilon >0$. For $m \ge 2/\epsilon + 1$, you have $0 \le \inf \{b_m \mid m \ge n\} \le \epsilon$ hence $0 \le \liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n \le \epsilon$. As this is true for all $\epsilon >0$ you have $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n =0$.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Because I know that the sequence can be divided into two subsqeuences.

Comment: Could you help me set up the problem?

Comment: See additional elements in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading.

Comment: I actually do no understand this. I do not think this is a $\epsilon - \delta$ proof. It is a $\epsilon-$ proof. Also, I'm not sure what you use for the proof. Is far as I can se it is only the definition of limes inferior.